# Shopware 6 How can make I create filter with custom field?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

How can I create filter with customfields?

I update the Shopware 5 to Shopware 6 and some of my fields into customfields (eg: migration_ComuMess5_product_series, migration_ComuMess5_product_author, migration_ComuMess5_product_company ...)

Answer (score 1):

There is a page in the documentation about creating custom filters for the storefront.
Please take a look: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-listing-filters.html

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. Please post the details in your answer and only link to support those details. Links can die.

Answer (score 0):

It's because I didn't say it clearly.
I have created a filter with customfields bool but I am having difficulty creating a filter with string, which displays as mutiselect.
Here is my code:

Subscriber/migration_ComuMess5_product_series.php

```
<?php

namespace MyFilters\Subscriber;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Events\ProductListingCollectFilterEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Listing\Filter;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Aggregation\Bucket\FilterAggregation;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Aggregation\Metric\MaxAggregation;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsAnyFilter;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Aggregation\Metric\EntityAggregation;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\Listing\ProductListingResult;

class migration_ComuMess5_product_series implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ProductListingCollectFilterEvent::class => 'onProductListingCollectFilter',
        ];
    }

    public function onProductListingCollectFilter(ProductListingCollectFilterEvent $event): void
    {
        $filters = $event->getFilters();

        // Your logic to get the filter value
        $ids = $event->getRequest()->get('migration_ComuMess5_product_series');

        // Create an EqualsAnyFilter to check if the value exists in the array
        $equalsAnyFilter = new EqualsFilter(
            'product.customFields.migration_ComuMess5_product_series',
            $ids
        );

        // Wrap it in a Filter object
        $filter = new Filter(
            'filter-migration_ComuMess5_product_series',
            !empty($ids),
            [new EntityAggregation('migration_ComuMess5_product_series', 'product.customFields.migration_ComuMess5_product_series', 'product_migration_ComuMess5_product_series')],
            $equalsAnyFilter,
            $ids
        );

        // Add the filter to the collection
        $filters->add($filter);

    }
}
```

services.xml

```
<service id="MyFilters\Subscriber\migration_ComuMess5_product_series">
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

filter-panel.html.twig

```
{% set migration_ComuMess5_product_series = listing.aggregations.get('migration_ComuMess5_product_series') %}
{{ dump(migration_ComuMess5_product_series) }}
{% if migration_ComuMess5_product_series is empty %}
{% set migration_ComuMess5_product_seriesSorted = migration_ComuMess5_product_series.entities|sort((a, b) => a.translated.name|lower <=> b.translated.name|lower) %}
    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/listing/filter/filter-multi-select.html.twig' with {
        elements: migration_ComuMess5_product_seriesSorted,
        sidebar: sidebar,
        name: 'migration_ComuMess5_product_series',
        displayName: 'migration_ComuMess5_product_series'|trans|sw_sanitize
    } %}
{% endif %}
```

Bug: EntityRepository for entity "product_migration_ComuMess5_product_series" does not exist.

Comment: You declared "migration_ComuMess5_product_series" as the entity to search in EntityAggregation, but that is your custom field. What do you want to search for, ProductSeries?

Answer (score 0):

I want create a filter based on my customfield "migration_ComuMess5_product_series"

Here is another code that worked:

```
class migration_ComuMess5_product_neti_purchase_blocker implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            ProductListingCollectFilterEvent::class => 'addFilter'
        ];
    }

    public function addFilter(ProductListingCollectFilterEvent $event)
    {
        $filters = $event->getFilters();
        
        $value = (bool) $event->getRequest()->get('migration_ComuMess5_product_neti_purchase_blocker');
       
        $customFieldFilter = new Filter(
            'filter_migration_ComuMess5_product_neti_purchase_blocker',
            $value, 
            [],
            new EqualsFilter('product.customFields.migration_ComuMess5_product_neti_purchase_blocker', $value),
            $value
        );
        
        $filters->add($customFieldFilter);
    }

}
```

filter-panel.html.twig

```
{% sw_include '@MyFilters/storefront/component/listing/filter/filter-boolean-customfields.html.twig' with {
    name: 'migration_ComuMess5_product_neti_purchase_blocker',
    displayName: 'product neti purchase blocker'|trans|sw_sanitize
} %}
```

The difference between them is that one is a bool, the other is a string.